# Viewing a large (12.5GB) HDF5 file written using h5py on HDFView 2.14

Tags: python, out-of-memory, hdf5, h5py, hdf

I have a very large HDF5 file created using Python/ h5py. I cannot open the file on HDFView 2.14, when I try to open the file nothing happens. Any suggestions on how I can open/ view the file? It contains just 5 datasets, but each dataset has 778 million rows.. hence the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know it's a size issue?  Does HDFView work for a smaller file from the same source?  Error messages?

Comment: Just fixed it- turns out I could solve the problem by compressing the file using gzip compression :) Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Hi, I encounter a similar problem with a 60GB h5 file. could you explain how to  compress the file using gzip?After compress will it be a .rar file?Then how could this be opened in hdfviewer? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit your hdfview.bat and add more memory on the switch

this is the line on .bat file:
start "HDFView" "%JAVABIN%\javaw.exe" %JAVAOPTS% -Xmx1024M -Djava.library.path="%INSTALLDIR%\lib;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\ext" -Dhdfview.root="%INSTALLDIR%" -cp "%INSTALLDIR%\lib\fits.jar;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\netcdf.jar;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\jarhdf-3.3.2.jar;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\jarhdf5-3.3.2.jar;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\extra\slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar;%INSTALLDIR%\lib\HDFView.jar" hdf.view.HDFView %*

you can edit -Xmx1024M to more like: -Xmx4024M
it add more memory to java machine

Comment: It turns out the solution was much simpler, all I had to do was use GZIP compression and it all worked out :) thanks anyway!